# Injected members from the host language to arrive to guest language as guest language types

Tags: graalvm

This question is somewhat related to: 
[GraalVM - Using Polyglot Value without a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669154/graalvm-using-polyglot-value-without-a-context)

In my application, the code snippets run in the guest languages should not need to know that the arguments injected (through members of the bindings) are Java arguments. Instead, for people developing in the guest language, arguments should look like just another argument of the guest language itself.

For example, I would like for an array injected from my Java host language to a JS guest script, in this fashion:

```
Value guestLanguageBindings = context.getBindings(scriptData.getLanguage().toString());

guestLanguageBindings.putMember(argumentName, argumentValue);
```

to "arrive" to the guest language as a JS array, not as a java.util.ArrayList as it is happening right now.

Currently I got around this problem by converting every non primitive type (I noticed that String, int, etc. arrive to JS as JS "types") to JSON and converting back in the guest language.

This works, but I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to do it or if indeed using the bindings is the right way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @Christian Humer suggesting to use ProxyArray is a good one, and is explanation on how to put together a ProxyArray is correct and well presented.

However, my requirement was to be able to present the array argument (set using the top level bindings) as if it was a guest language data type. ProxyArray only get me halfway there, with the resulting data type being a Java type and not for example a JS type.

In order to fully achieve the above, since I am in control of the Java host side, I have created up-front a JS array using the Context, on the host side, and copied the content of the Java ArrayList in it. When calling the guest code, I simply set the JS array in the bindings, which is already a fully featured JS array.

```
    Value jsArray = context.eval("js", "new Array();");

    jsArray.setArrayElement(0, 1001); //array will grow automatically, JS semantics
    jsArray.setArrayElement(1, 1002);
    jsArray.setArrayElement(2, 1003);

    guestLanguageBindings.putMember("variable", jsArray);
    context.eval("js", "print(variable);");
```

This approach was suggested to me [on Github](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/45) when I filed the bug report mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 5):

> This works, but I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to do it or if indeed using the bindings is the right way to go?

As you have noticed when you put in Java objects into a polyglot language they will look like Java objects and not like JavaScript objects to the user. In order to make them mimic guest language objects you may use the Polyglot Proxy API.

Example for JS objects (backed by HashMap):

```java
try (Context context = Context.create("js")) {
    Map<String, Object> backingMap = new HashMap<>();
    backingMap.put("foo", "bar");
    context.getBindings("js").putMember("hostObject", ProxyObject.fromMap(backingMap));
    assert "bar".equals(context.eval("js", "hostObject.foo").asString());
    backingMap.put("foo", "baz");
    assert "baz".equals(context.eval("js", "hostObject.foo").asString());
}
```

Example for JS arrays (backed by Java array):

```java
try (Context context = Context.create("js")) {
    Object[] backingArray = new Object[42];
    backingArray[0] = 42;
    context.getBindings("js").putMember("hostObject", ProxyArray.fromArray(backingArray));
    assert 42 == context.eval("js", "hostObject[0]").asInt();
    backingArray[0] = 43;
    assert 43 == context.eval("js", "hostObject[0]").asInt();
}
```

Example for functions (backed by Lambda):

```java
try (Context context = Context.create("js")) {
    ProxyExecutable executable = (arguments) -> arguments[0];
    context.getBindings("js").putMember("hostObject",executable);
    assert 42 == context.eval("js", "hostObject(42)").asInt();
    assert 43 == context.eval("js", "hostObject(43)").asInt();
}
```

You may also implement ProxyObject and ProxyArray directly to customize the behavior, e.g. if you want to provide a read-only object or array.

Here is another Proxy Example: http://www.graalvm.org/docs/graalvm-as-a-platform/embed/#computed-arrays-using-polyglot-proxies

Proxy Javadoc: http://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/proxy/package-summary.html

Comment: Apologies for posting for a clarification only after some time. I have updated my code to use ProxyArray.fromArray(). However in the JS side (guest language) the array is not seen as a JS array, instead it is of type: org.graalvm.polyglot.proxy.ProxyArray (also a Java type). This means that it is not possible using the array as if it were a regular JS array. Statements like arr[0] (such as in your example) work, however specific calls such as arr.sort() fail. I was hoping that the array could have been used in the guest side just like a JS array. Is that not possible?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ideally js builtins just work for interop types like ProxyArray. However coverage in graal.js is not quite complete yet. It would be great if you could report a bug to https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. Sure, I will submit a bug report. Could you please elaborate on this a little: **"Ideally js builtins just work for interop types like ProxyArray."** Not sure I understood exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: FYI, here is my bug report with additional info: https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/issues/45